# null terminator in the middle of a string

Tags: c, string, terminator

what happens if a program receives as an argv[1] argument a string with a null terminator in the middle? for example:

```
./program test'\0'example
```

what is the value of argv[1]? is it test? is it test\0example? I have these lines of code

```
max = sizeof(filename);
len = strlen(argv[1]);
if (len > max) goto error;
strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
```

I need to build an exploit for this program and what I wanted to do, is making argv[1] worth test'\0'example so strlen(argv[1])=strlen("test")=4 and strcpy(filename, argv[1])=strcpy(filename, "test") so I can use the rest of the string (the example part) to put my exploit. is it possible? thank you very much?

Comment: `strlen` and `strcpy` both stop on a null character, so that won't make a difference. It doesn't look like that input will feed in a null character anyways.

Comment: I rather doubt that most shells will even pass anything beyond the null char.

Comment: Hint: Think about how many bytes a string of length `n` requires.

Comment: I don't think that's a null character: `echo test'\0'example` -> `test\0example`...

Comment: This is, at least in bash: echo test$'\000'example

Comment: In C, one cannot have a `'\0'` in the _middle_ of a string.  By definition, the string ends with the `'\0'`.   A `char` array could have a `'\0'` in the _middle_, but not a string.

Comment: If such a thing were possible the bash syntax would be `./program "foo"$'\0'"bar"`. However it is not possible to pass a `\0` in the middle of an argument. The reason is, any shell passing arguments will eventually have to call one of the exec family of functions, and these which require `\0`-terminated strings. http://linux.die.net/man/3/execve

Comment: @Arkadiy `echo -n test$'\000'example | wc -c`

Comment: @Arkadiy For comparison try `printf 'test\0example' | wc -c` That one gives the correct answer since the NUL character is not actually passed via the commandlie, but rather the printf program iterprets the two characters `\0` and converts it into a NUL on stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv[1]` is a pointer object of type `char*`. Its value is an address, not a string. Specifically, its value is the address of a `char` object whose value is `'t'`.

The C standard (in section 7.1.1) has the following definitions:

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
> character.
> [...]
> A *pointer to a string* is a pointer to its initial (lowest addressed) character. The *length of a string* is the number of bytes preceding the null character and
> the *value of a string* is the sequence of the values of the contained characters, in order.

Since `argv[1]` points to the first of a contiguous sequence of characters, one of which is a null character, it's a pointer to a string. The value of that string is "test" (which includes the terminating `'\0'`), and the length of the string is 4.

It's common to say, as a kind of verbal shorthand, that the value of `argv[1]` is `"test"`, but that's imprecise -- *especially* in a case like this where the distinction between the value of a string and the value of the array containing that string is significant.

`argv[1]` also points to the first character of an *array* of characters. The first 5 bytes of that array contain the string `"test"`. The entire array contains the character values:

```
{ 't', 'e', 's', 't',
  '\0',
  'e', 'x', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e',
  '\0' }
```

If you pass the value of `argv[1]` to a string function, that function will only see `"test"`, and will not access anything past the terminating `'\0'`. The rest of the contents of the array are still perfectly valid, and can be accessed using functions (like `memcpy`) that don't just operate on strings.

Whether it's possible to invoke your main program in such a way that `argv[1]` will point to the first element of an array with those particular contents is another matter, one that depends on your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `argv[1]` will be `"test"`, assuming you actually manage to get a real NULL character on the terminal and not just the literal characters `\` and `0`.

As RedAlert's comment mentioned, `strlen` and `strcpy` both stop on a null character, so getting a null character will not help for most exploits.

You most likely need to find a way to do the exploit without using the character `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea works when `main()` is called from within `main()`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc == 1) {
    char *data[] = {"", "5one\0two", "7three\0four", "6five\0six"};
    main(4, data); // call main again, with exploitable data
  } else {
    if (!argv[0][0]) { // test for empty argv[0]
      for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%s ==> %s\n", argv[i] + 1, argv[i] + argv[i][0] - '0');
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if it will work when `main()` is called from the C library initialization code ... or even if you can make your shell accept a NUL character as part of an argument.